# proof of an equivalence

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove something by induction, and in induction step I had to prove this
$$1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil{\frac{n-1}{2}}\rceil} (-1)^{k}\frac{(t^2)^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}(-1)^k \frac{(t^2)^{2k}}{(2k)!}. $$
Any Idea?

**Edit** : (the first one is solved)
what about this equality
$$ -\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}}\rfloor}(-1)^{k-1} \frac{(t^2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{(t^2)^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!} $$

Comment: It does not hold. Just compute the case $n=2$.

Comment: @jonh I modified it , I forgot to add $+1$ to the LHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embbed the "$1+$" as the 0 th summand in the left summatory, and then your equality follows from the fact that $\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil=\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor$. You can see this easily splitting the cases where $n$ is even and odd.

Edit:[You're very welcome] For the second equality just make the change of summation $k\leftarrow k-1$. Then the right sum is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil n/2\right\rceil -1}(-1)^k\frac{(t^2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=-\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil n/2\right\rceil -1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(t^2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
And the equality follows cause $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lceil n/2\right\rceil-1$. You can check this again by splitting in the even and odd cases.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.
I added another equality to be checked in my post.

Comment: Sorry, I found the solution for the second equation.
Just change the index of the LHF with $k'=k+1$ where $k'$ is the new index.

Comment: @J.Mccain I posted the second answer before O saw your comment. Gonna leave it like this. :)